# Parse .a2l and .hex files

Tags: hex

I'm trying to parse some **.a2l** and **.hex** files to extract variables and their values. So far l don't know how to find the values of the variables in the .hex file. Here is a [link](https://wiki.asam.net/display/STANDARDS/ASAM+CDF#ASAMCDF-Downloads) to download an example of these files. 
To be more specific : How can I read the value at the address 0x810600 in the .hex file ?

```
/begin CHARACTERISTIC ASAM.C.DEPENDENT.REF_1.SWORD
  "Dependent SWORD" 
  VALUE 
  0x810600                                             
  RL.FNC.SWORD.ROW_DIR                                 
  0 
  CM.IDENTICAL
  -32268 32267
  /begin DEPENDENT_CHARACTERISTIC 
     "X1 + 5" 
     ASAM.C.SCALAR.SBYTE.IDENTICAL                    
  /end DEPENDENT_CHARACTERISTIC
  DISPLAY_IDENTIFIER DI.ASAM.C.DEPENDENT.REF_1.SWORD
/end CHARACTERISTIC
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same A2L, please find RL.FNC.SWORD.ROW_DIR item, I guess it might be kind of signed word (2 bytes) type.

I'm not sure if this is kind of array or some special type... I assume this is just single variable (scalar).

Again, find CM.IDENTICAL item, as it's name maybe it's identical compu_method. This means HEX value 0 -> displayed screen as 0, HEX value 100 -> displayed screen as 100, ... identical between internal value and physical value. No special conversion I guess.

Go to the address 0x810600 in HEX then you can find some values there. As it is identical compu_method type, the value in HEX might be identically displayed in M/C SW (INCA, Vision, CANape, ...) I guess.

Answer (score 0):

HEX is of [intel hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) format. This format is used to map each part of the file to a part in virtual address space of device. You can also use the following command if you use Linux:

`objdump -s file.hex`